# how to restrict a page to open only one time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have developed a application in which there is a update page which is open only when the application is installed in the device and application run for the first time.After that update page is not shown.
How can I perform this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is take one bool variable in nsuserdefaults and when app will first launch it will set it to no.After that when you have shown your download page set that bool variable to yes.
Now every time when your app will get opened put a check mark that if your that bool variable is yes so dont show your download page or else what you what to do.

fIRST TIME YOU NEED TO DO:-

```
     NSUserDefaults *std3Defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    
    [std3Defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"update"];

Next time you need to check:-
```

IN viewdidload of downlaod page:-

```
NSUserDefaults *std3Defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    BOOL check=[std3Defaults boolForKey:@"update"];
    if (check==YES) {
//dont show update page
    }
else
{
//show update page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use userdefaults

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Update"]==nil)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"Update"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

At first time only it will go inside if condition after that this condition always false